Unhandled Runtime Error after upgrading to Gatsby 5 Error in function computeKey in ./node_modules/@prefresh/core/src/computeKey.js:9
I am testing to upgrade my Gatsby 4 project to Gatsby 5 project. after upgrading all required modules, when I run gatsby develop; I saw issues showed in localhost
unhandled runtime error
Error in function computeKey in ./node_modules/@prefresh/core/src/computeKey.js:9  

 7 |  */
   8 | export const computeKey = signature => {
>  9 |   let fullKey = signature.key;
  10 |   let hooks;
  11 |
  12 |   try {

and here is what console gave me
debug.module.js:7 Uncaught 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')
    at computeKey (computeKey.js:14:27)
    at Object.sign (index.js:40:82)
    at commons.js:3105:45
    at eval (modal.js:6:1)
    at ./src/components/modal.js (component---src-temp…c-page-js.js:1344:1)
    at options.factory (commons.js:3116:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (commons.js:2437:33)
    at fn (commons.js:2761:21)
    at eval (playbackButton.js:9:64)
    at ./src/components/playbackButton.js (component---src-temp…c-page-js.js:1355:1)

Other pages were running ok, just when I tried to enter localhost for the home page it showed such issue.
Anything I should be aware of for troubleshooting. I had no experience dealing with issues from node modules(I assumed). Any hints will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!
cleaned cache and did clean build, but issues persist
